Approximating a Communication Traffic Model with a Poisson Process
I’m working on a problem related to communication networks, specifically modeling traffic at a network node. The traffic arrives at a relatively high rate, and the model I’m dealing with is not in a regime where the frame length $\tau$ is much smaller than the transmission intermission.
The traffic process at the node includes a fixed dead time after each event (e.g., packet transmission), followed by an intermission that follows an exponential distribution. This setup makes the process somewhat similar to a Type II counter model with a fixed dead time and a random inter-arrival time.
To simplify my analysis, I’m attempting to approximate this complex model using a Poisson process. Assuming the packet length is 1, I have:
$$
\lambda_{\text{eff}} = \frac{1}{1 + 1/\lambda} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + 1}
$$
I’ve run some simulations, and it appears that the approximation fits well. However, I’m concerned about how well this approximation holds in terms of process behavior.

Are there any known methods or approximations that can help simplify this type of model while retaining reasonable accuracy?
If there are references or papers that discuss approximating such processes with Poisson models, they would be incredibly helpful.

Any insights, suggestions, or references would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
